# Need to find source_location of class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a class method.

Like:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.mymethod
   end
   def instance_something
   end
end
```

How can I find the source_location of a class method in Ruby?

If I want the source location of "instance_something" I do

```
School.new.method(:instance_something).source_location
```

But I can't do that with class method.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in irb, and it works.

```
class Foo
  def foo
  end
  def self.bar
  end
end

f = Foo.new
m1 = f.method(:foo)
m1.source_location
 => ["(irb)", 2] 

Foo.method(:bar)
m2 = Foo.method(:bar)
m2.source_location
 => ["(irb)", 4]
```